# Stop JavaScript function when element is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I want a function that will stop another function from running. It can be in JavaScript or jQuery.

It is for a game so div 1 is clicked over and over.

```
var makeBox=//a function;
$("#div1").click(function () {

   makeBox     

});


$("#div2").click(function () {

   //stop make box 

});
```

I hope it's more clear now

Comment: Its not clear your problem, what have you tried ? Can you paste some of your code ?

Comment: Do you just want to remove the click event handler on `#div1` when `#div2` is clicked on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try reassigning the event handler function?

```
var makeBox=//a function;
$("#div1").click(function () {

    makeBox     

});


$("#div2").click(function () {
    $("#div1").click(function(){
        //Do nothing
    });
});
```

You might need to reassign it again later if you want it to work again but I don''t know exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

No. JavaScript is single threaded. The click event won't be processed while another function is running.

(Your function might call other functions, using events, timeouts, etc which would allow for interruption, but there isn't any indication of that in your question).